# Redistribute entries into multiple rows in a huge pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame (derived from a CSV file) with about 100M entries that looks like this:

```
df1:

        var1     var2
0          1        2
1          2        1
2          1  {3,4,5}
3          5        6
4  {4,5,6,7}        8
```

I need to convert this into a new data frame in which  (for every row) each element in the braces needs to be associated with the element in the other column, i.e.,

```
df2:

  var1 var2
0    1    2
1    2    1
2    1    3
3    1    4
4    1    5
5    5    6
6    4    8
7    5    8
8    6    8
9    7    8
```

Each element is a string, even the brace entry itself. Note that the brace element can be in either column. Does anyone know how can I achieve this efficiently for a dataset of about 100M entries? Thanks in advance.

Python example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': '1', 'var2': '2'},
               {'var1': '2', 'var2': '1'},
               {'var1': '1', 'var2': '{3,4,5}'},
               {'var1': '5', 'var2': '6'},
               {'var1': '{4,5,6,7}', 'var2': '8'}])


df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': '1', 'var2': '2'},
               {'var1': '2', 'var2': '1'},
               {'var1': '1', 'var2': '3'},
               {'var1': '1', 'var2': '4'},
               {'var1': '1', 'var2': '5'},
               {'var1': '5', 'var2': '6'},
               {'var1': '4', 'var2': '8'},
               {'var1': '5', 'var2': '8'},
               {'var1': '6', 'var2': '8'},
               {'var1': '7', 'var2': '8'}])
```

I have done this so far but it is slow and uses another data frame.

```
# Put row with braces in the second column
def swap_cols(row):
    if '{' in row[0]:
        return (row[1], row[0])
    return row

# Convert the braces into a list
def parse_str(s):
    if '{' in s:
        s = s[1:-1]
        return s.split(',')
    return [s]


df3 = df1.apply(swap_cols, axis=1)

df3.var2 = df3.var2.apply(parse_str)

# Show that it works
for ridx, row in df3.iterrows():
    for ele in row.var2:
        print row.var1, ele
```

Comment: I added the numpy tag, this could attract interesting answers :)

Comment: So none of the answers was helpful? I'd be interested to see real-life performance comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.vstack` with `np.meshgrid` and `reshape` i.e

```
sdf = df.apply(lambda x:(x.str.strip('{}').str.split(',')))

def cartesian(x): 
    return np.vstack(np.array([np.array(np.meshgrid(*i)).T.reshape(-1,2) for i in x.values]))

ndf = pd.DataFrame(cartesian(sdf),columns=sdf.columns)
```

If you want to strip and split and then apply cartesian

```
%%time 
100 loops, best of 3: 4 ms per loop
```

If you do have striped and splited dataframe then:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 564 µs per loop
```

Output:

```
  var1 var2
0    1    2
1    2    1
2    1    3
3    1    4
4    1    5
5    5    6
6    4    8
7    5    8
8    6    8
9    7    8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
# isolate these cases as they will be treated separately
case1 = df1['var1'].str.contains('{')
case2 = df1['var2'].str.contains('}')

# convert to lists
import ast
df1 = df1.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace('{', '[').str.replace('}', ']')) \
         .applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

In the second case:

```
df1[case2].groupby('var1')['var2'].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(g.sum())) \
          .reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Applying `sum` will concatenate the lists (if there are more than one) for each value of `var1`, and casting to a `pandas.Series` will give the shape you are looking for.

You can then concatenate everything back:

```
pd.concat([
    df1[~case1 & ~case2],
    df1[case1].groupby('var2')['var1'].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(g.sum())).reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index(),
    df1[case2].groupby('var1')['var2'].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(g.sum())).reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index()
]).sort_values('var1')  # sorting optional
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for flattening:

```
#create lists by remove {} and split
splitted1 = df1['var1'].str.strip('{}').str.split(',')
#get legths of lists
lens1 = splitted1.str.len()

splitted2 = pd.Series(np.repeat(df1['var2'].values, lens1)).str.strip('{}').str.split(',')
lens2 = splitted2.str.len()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.repeat(np.concatenate(splitted1), lens2),
                   'b':np.concatenate(splitted2)})
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  1  3
3  1  4
4  1  5
5  5  6
6  4  8
7  5  8
8  6  8
9  7  8
```